# Accepting selective folders from a component in RTC using command line

Tags: command-line, version-control, rational-team-concert

I have an RTC (IBM Rational Team Concert) Stream, call it as "ABCStream" within that stream I have folder like 'A', 'B' ,'C' and there could be nested folders within A or B or C folder.

```
ABCStream
  |-------A
          |-- other Subfolders

  |-------B
  |-------C
```

In workspace "WS-A" only folder "A" is loaded. I am creating a command line utility where I want to accept all changes coming for folder 'A'.  I am not sure how to do that. I can accept all incoming changes for a component but not just for a subfolder within a component. I want to accept  incoming changes only for folder "A" and its subfolders not for folder "B" and "C".
Here is the command line reference I am using.

[scm reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.4/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/accept.html)

any leads will be helpful?

Thanks!